# Angular service reset when changing page through Angular routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-routing, angular-services

I have multi page signUp form , I need to persist data until last step , so that user can jump to any step back and edit.

I am using service "User" as singleton object for all six steps.

**userService.js**

```
myApp.service('User',function($http,Auth,$location,$rootScope){
 var register; 
 var c_user = [];

 // Using Angular Devise plugin
 // Sample user Response
 // {"id":1,"email":"demo@gmail.com","mobile":"8951112312","name":"","admin":true,"created_at":"2014-06-25T12:07:33.000Z","updated_at":"2014-08-19T06:36:55.000Z"}

 Auth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
  c_user.push(user);
 });

 return {
   register:register,
   c_user:c_user
 }
})
```

**headerController.js**

```
function headerController($scope,User) {
 $scope.c_user = User.c_user;
 $scope.reg = User.register;
 $scope.$watch( function () { return User.register; }, function ( register ) {
   $scope.reg = User.register;
 });
}
```

**signUpController.js**

```
function signUpController($scope,User) {
 $scope.$watch('user', function(user){
  User.register = user;
 });
}
```

This binding works , so when I change $scope.user , the service variable getting updated which getting reflected in other controllers too. But when I change page , the service object                               "User.register" is getting reset. Below is my routes and view.

**routes.js.erb**

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
 .state('register',
  { url: "/register/:step",
    templateUrl: "/assets/user/register.html",
    controller: "signUpController" })
});
```

**register.html**

```
<div ng-show="step == 1">
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.step1.name">
</div>

<div ng-show="step == 2">
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.step1.email">
</div>

<div ng-show="step == 3">
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.step1.mobile">
</div>

<a href="/register/{{1* step +1}}" ng-show="1* step < 3"> Proceed to Step {{1* step +1}}</a>
<a href="/register/{{1* step -1}}" ng-show="1* step > 1"> Back to Step {{1* step -1}}</a>
```

***Irrelevant to above question***

**@apairet : HeaderController scenario**

I am using AngularJs with rails application where I has Application layout and ui-view.

```
<header>
<div class="logo-header" ng-controller="headerController">
  <span class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/assets/logo.png"></a></span>
  <span class="header-icons pull-right">
    <span ng-show="c_user[0]">
      Hi, {{c_user[0].name}}
      <a href="#" ng-click="logout()"> <i class="fa fa-stop"></i> </a>
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="c_user[0]">
      <a href="/register/1">
        <span>SIGN UP NOW<span>
      </a> | 
      <a href="/login">
        <span>SIGN IN NOW<span>
      </a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="menu-header">
  <paper-icon-button class="menu-icon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
  <span flex>MUTUAL FUNDS</span>
</div>
</header>
<body>
  <div ui-view> </div>
</body>
```

I am using User service to store the current user info and header controller using the service. I initially tried to use same "signUpcontroller" for header

but when I navigate to the signup page , the controller getting initiated two times, So i thought to create separate controller to handle header UI bindings.

Comment: Thank for updating your question. Where is 'c_user' initiated? You use it in the view but there nothing like '$scope.c_user = ...' in your controller! Would it be possible to set up a plunkr or a jsfiddle?

Comment: @apairet : Thanks again for quick response , I updated question. I will setup Jsfiddle if above update is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why it fails:
Each time you change route, the controller 'signUpController.js' will be instantiated. When it is instantiated, several $digest cycle are performed and the watch is called accordingly. When run for the first time, your watch expression will return 'undefined'. You can test it by setting up console.log inside you watch expression:

```
function signUpController($scope,User) {
    var count = 0;
    $scope.$watch('user', function(user){
        console.log(count, user)
        count += 1;

        User.register = user;
    });
}
```

You could **fix** it by assigning $scope.user to User.register:

```
function signUpController($scope,User) {
    $scope.user = User.register;
    $scope.$watch('user', function(user){
        User.register = user;
    });
}
```

However the $watch expression is useless since you are using ngModel. Your controller could be simplified to:

```
function signUpController($scope,User) {
    $scope.user = User.register;
}
```

Moreover, I do not understand the purpose of your headerController. Can you show how you use it and explain its goal?

Comment: Thanks for quick answer , it really helped. I added scenario about headerController to question , If you have better solution for same , it will be helpful.